# Low level question about how eth_estimateGas interacts with state changes

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, gas-estimate

i'm new here, i have a pretty weird question.

Do you guys know how eth_estimateGas works at low level? In particular, do you guys know how it interacts with state changes?
Let's say for example i have a smart contract like this:

> *bool public methodActive = false;*
>
> *function test() { require(methodActive); }*
>
> *function flipActive() { methodActive = !methodActive; }*

If i call an estimateGas on the test() method, it will correctly return an error.

Now, let's say i call the flipActive() method by sending a tx.
I expect that the estimateGas on the test() method will still return me an error until the tx that calls the flipActive() method  gets mined and confirmed in a block.

But i had several instances where this wasn't the case, and the estimateGas would return me a correct value even tho the flipActive() tx was still in the mempool, pending.

This means that, if the test() method tx gets sent with an higher priority than the flipActive() one, it will actually frontrun it and get reverted, which is very much inconstistend with the estimateGas  simulation.

Why does this happen? Is a way to prevent this?
Is the estimateGas simulation run with current state ( last mined block )
or the pending transactions get thrown in the mix aswell?